# Vector spanning sets

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Is there a simpler way to prove the following statement?

> If $\{\mathbf{u_1}, \mathbf{u_2}, \mathbf{u_3}\}$ is a spanning set for $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $\{\mathbf{u_1}, \mathbf{u_1}+\mathbf{u_2}, \mathbf{u_1}-\mathbf{u_3}\}$ also spans $\mathbb{R}^n$.

This is what I've come up with:

To save time I will only prove for $n=2$ because the proofs for $n=1$ and $n=3$ use similar logic

**Case $n=2$**
let $\mathbf{u_1}=\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}$, $\mathbf{u_2}=\begin{bmatrix}c\\d\end{bmatrix}$, $\mathbf{u_3}=\begin{bmatrix}e\\f\end{bmatrix}$  for arbitrary $a,b,c,d,e,f\in \mathbb{R}$
so the augmented matrix for $\{\mathbf{u_1}, \mathbf{u_2}, \mathbf{u_3}\}$ is $\begin{bmatrix}a & c & e\\b & d & f\end{bmatrix}$ To put this in echelon form I will multiply row 1 by $-\frac{b}{a}$ then add it to row 2 to get $\begin{bmatrix}a & c & e\\0 & -\frac{bc}{a}+d & -\frac{be}{a}+f\end{bmatrix}$ And since $\{\mathbf{u_1}, \mathbf{u_2}, \mathbf{u_3}\}$ spans $\mathbb{R}^2$, row 2 in the echelon matrix must have a pivot, meaning $-\frac{bc}{a}+d \not=0$ or $-\frac{be}{a}+f \not= 0$. Now if I create the augmented matrix for $\{\mathbf{u_1}, \mathbf{u_1}+\mathbf{u_2}, \mathbf{u_1}-\mathbf{u_3}\}$ I get $\begin{bmatrix}a & a+c & a-e\\b & b+d & b-f\end{bmatrix}$ To put this in echelon form I will once again multiply row 1 by $-\frac{b}{a}$ then add it to row 2 to get $\begin{bmatrix}a & a+c & a-e\\0 & -\frac{bc}{a}+d & -\left(-\frac{be}{a}+f\right)\end{bmatrix}$ and since I proved above that $-\frac{bc}{a}+d \not=0$ or $-\frac{be}{a}+f \not= 0$, then there must be a pivot in row 2, meaning that $\{\mathbf{u_1}, \mathbf{u_1}+\mathbf{u_2}, \mathbf{u_1}-\mathbf{u_3}\}$ also spans $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: Yes, there is. But consider also showing a bit more commitment here; have you tried something?

Comment: If $n > 3$, your assumption is already wrong.

Comment: @Zhanxiong: so what? The statement is true for $n > 3$ trivially.

Comment: @PeterFranek updated

Comment: @RobArthan  Maybe I missed something, but how can three vectors span the space of $\mathbb{R}^4$, say?

Comment: @Zhanxiong They can't. The statement is an implication so if the part before the "then" is false, then the entire statement is true.

Comment: @gommb OK then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(u_1, u_2, u_3)$ spans $\mathbb{R}^n$, then for any $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, there exist $a_1, a_2, a_3\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x=a_1 u_1+a_2 u_2+a_3 u_3$. With very little algebra, we obtain $x=(a_3-a_2+a_1)u_1+a_2 (u_1+u_2)-a_3(u_1-u_3)$, which means $x\in span(u_1, u_1+u_2, u_1-u_3)$. Hence, $(u_1, u_1+u_2, u_1-u_3)$ spans $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\u}{\mathbf{u}}$
$\newcommand{\span}{\mathrm{span}}$
$\newcommand{\real}{\mathbb{R}}$

Note the transition matrix from $\{\u_1, \u_2, \u_3\}$ to $\{\u_1, \u_1 + \u_2, \u_1 - \u_3\}$ is given by
\begin{align*}
(\u_1, \u_1 + \u_2, \u_1 - \u_3) = (\u_1, \u_2, \u_3)\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix} =: (\u_1, \u_2, \u_3)A.
\end{align*}

Since the matrix $A$ is invertible, $\span(\u_1, \u_2, \u_3) = \span(\u_1, \u_1 + \u_2, \u_1 - \u_3)$. To see this, given $\real^n = \span(\u_1, \u_2, \u_3)$, where $n \leq 3$, any $\alpha \in \real^n$ is a linear combination of $\u_1, \u_2, \u_3$, i.e., there exist $x_1, x_2, x_3 \in \real$ such that
\begin{align*}
\alpha = x_1\u_1 + x_2\u_2 + x_3\u_3 = (\u_1, \u_2, \u_3)\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix} = (\u_1, \u_1 + \u_2, \u_1 - \u_3) A^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix},
\end{align*}
showing that $\alpha \in \span(\u_1, \u_1 + \u_2, \u_1 - \u_3)$. Therefore $\real^n \subset \span(\u_1, \u_1 + \u_2, \u_1 - \u_3)$. This completes the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Let $B = \text{span} \{u_1, u_1 + u_2, u_1 - u_3\}$.

Then we have $(u_1 + u_2) - u_1 = u_2 \in B $. Similarly $u_3 \in B$. So $u_1, u_2, u_3 \in B$.

This gives $\text{span} \{u_1, u_2, u_3\} \subseteq B$. Since $u_1, u_1 + u_2, u_1 - u_3 \in \text{span}\{u_1, u_2, u_3 \}$, $B \subseteq \text{span} \{u_1, u_2, u_3\}$.

Thus $\mathbb{R}^n = \text{span} \{u_1, u_2, u_3\} = B$.